# How to remove superfluous padding caused by placing a textarea inside a Bootstrap tab pane?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm simply trying to display a textarea control inside a Twitter Bootstrap tab pane. I want the textarea to span the entire width of the tab pane, so I've added the `row-fluid` class to it. This works, but there seems to be some additional padding added to the textarea, causing a nasty horizontal scrollbar to show across the tab pane.

Here's a screenshot to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: Screenshot]

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZjDQ/1/).

How can I get rid of the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove (or if not possible, override) the `overflow:auto;` on the `<div>` with the class `.tabcontent`, e.g.

```
div.tab-content {
  overflow:visible;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JZjDQ/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like how you removed the textarea padding. It pushes all the text to the edge.

Comment: @Xå-k9IdI'-I0llwlg'I- Sorry - that was an accident (I forgot to take out of the fiddle :P)

Answer (score 1):

or give a smaller width that doesn't overflow the scroll

```
.text_area {
    width: 200px;
}
```

or

```
.text_area {
    width: 90%;
}
```